# Dynamic styling on a complex selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js

I have this styling on a vue component to alter a bootstrap component;

```
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: #f16e01;
  border-color: #707070;
}
```

How can I make background-color here set dynamically to equal a data string for example `colorData`? In other instances I would make a data style object and set it with :style, but due to the complex selector here I don't think I can do that.

I have jquery in my app so if it makes sense to use that somehow on my created hook and have it run after render somehow that's also okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you can't access the `before` element in jquery and neither add the data attribute to your css. You can however, create new classes ,that manipulate the before element, for your different colors and toggle these when the checkbox gets checked, based on a data attribute. Like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.custom-checkbox > .custom-control-input').change(function() {
    let colorClass= $(this).data('color') + '-checkbox';
    $(this).siblings('.custom-control-label').toggleClass( colorClass );
});
});
```

```css
.red-checkbox::before {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.green-checkbox::before {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" data-color="red">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Red checkbox</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2" data-color="green">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">green checkbox</label>
</div>
```